# How to stay on the same page until session expires?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, pageload

I have this aspx code here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MSSQLConnector;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class AdministratorPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If user run this page without logging in, it will redirect the user to the login page
            if (Session["adminlogin"] == null)
            {
               Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I go directly to the Administrator Page when session is null it will go to the login page. But when I press the login using username and password, The system will give me a message "That the browser has a Redirect Loop". What process should I make to make my AdminPage stays on the same page when I press the browser back button, it will only go to the LoginPage is the session is null or the session is terminated by a Logout Event handler. Or if possible if the user pressed the web browser back button, the system will alert the user "Do you want to log out" with a yes or no decision. If no the system will stay on the same page, if yes the session will be terminated and system redirects to the loginpage.

My code for Login Page:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MSSQLConnector;
using System.Data;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class OnlineAppSyss : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public void Admin()
        {
            //String decleration
            string adminusername = (this.UserName.Value);
            string adminpass = (this.Password.Value);

            try
            {
                if (adminusername == "admin" && adminpass == "cmpe1234")
                {
                    Session["adminlogin"] = adminusername;
                    Response.Redirect("AdministratorPage.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Username and password does not match. Try again');</script>");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Username and password does not match. Try again');</script>");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you already on the Administrator Page? In which case, the `else` clause might be constantly redirecting indefinitely. Try it without the `else`...

Comment: I did try, without the else function sir, But the system will redirect the page to the loginpage, but the session is still active. Just want my system to only go the loginpage when session is terminated.

Comment: I've edited my post sir.

Comment: In your `Page_Load` event on the AdministratorPage, can you assign `Session["adminlogin"]` to a variable, and set a breakpoint to see what it's value is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on this line of code: `public partial class AdministratorPage : System.Web.UI.Page`, I suppose that you're in the `Admin Page`.

Let's imagine, you go to `Admin Page` when your `Session["adminlogin"]` NOT NULL, then **the condition will go to the `else` part**:

```
    if (Session["adminlogin"] == null)
    {
       Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx", true);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("AdministratorPage.aspx", true);
    }
```

And it keeps returning you to the `Admin Page`. It's the reason for the loop. **The solution should be: remove the `else` part.**

> Just want my system to only go the loginpage when session is
>   terminated

This means that you prevent users from coming in `Login Page` when the `Session` still exist. The solution is: **check for the `Session` in your `Login Page`, then redirect to another page if needed.**

```
// Check for session existence
if (Session["adminlogin"] != null)
{
    // Redirect to another page
    Response.Redirect("AdministratorPage.aspx", true);
}
```

Comment: Happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

The system is giving a message "That the browser has a Redirect Loop" because of this part in your code.

```
  else
  {
       Response.Redirect("AdministratorPage.aspx", true);
  }
```

Whenever your login is successful you are redirecting the page to the same page(AdministratorPage.aspx) which is causing a redirect loop. 
**Remove the else part.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786544/how-to-stay-on-the-same-page-until-session-expires/32786686#comment53412055_32786544

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano Are you sure `Session["adminlogin"]` is not null after successful login?

Comment: Yes sir, I've edited my question I added the admin function

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano I don't see any mistakes in your admin function. place a break point and check. and also check for any typos.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my correct code for my question above:

For the login page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MSSQLConnector;
using System.Data;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class LoginPage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If session is not null  redirect to this page
            if (Session["adminlogin"] != null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("AdministratorPage.aspx", true);
            }
        }
        public void Admin()
        {
            //String decleration
            string adminusername = (this.UserName.Value);
            string adminpass = (this.Password.Value);

            try
            {
                if (adminusername == "admin" && adminpass == "cmpe1234")
                {
                    Session["adminlogin"] = adminusername;
                    Response.Redirect("AdministratorPage.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Username and password does not match. Try again');</script>");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Username and password does not match. Try again');</script>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the admin page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MSSQLConnector;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SoftwareAnalysisAndDesign.SAD
{
    public partial class AdministratorPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If session is null, go to login page
            if (Session["adminlogin"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this even pressing the web browser back button it will redirect to their current pages.